# How to replace multiple value in capturing group with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, xml

i have a very malformed xml file and i have to do a couple of fixes before parsing it.

In details, i have to replace a number of cdatas (open and close) between 2 given tags, and i'd like to do it with one regex.

I have some like:

`<tag>data...<!CDATA[...]]>...otherdata..!<CDATA[....]>>....</tag>`

What i would like to is replace all of the occurencies of cdata (start and stop, so `<!CDATA[` and `]>>`) betwenn the tag with nothing, removing them.

Thanks  a lot!

**EDIT 1:**

I have thousands of files. I have a regex that extract the content of the tag, i.e.

`(<tag>)(?!<\/tag>)(.)*(<\/tag>)`

but i cannot think of a way to insert a check inside the group, something like:

`^(!<CDATA[|]]>)*`

Comment: It is not a free regexp generator here mate. What did you try? Why are you stuck?

Comment: if its only 1 file your better off doing it manually then making sure that the xml doesn't get to that state in the future.

Comment: @sjahan never thought it was. I just didn't think my not working solution (that i've added now) was worth including.

Comment: @Lestat86 Always show what you did: here, people help to debug your code, not to do it for you. It is a good habit to take, otherwise, your post could get closed quite quickly! Here, you got already 3 votes to close it!

Comment: @sjahan holy crap, didn't see the downvotes "-.- I didn't post anything because i miss the core part... i'll always include the code from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a fairly nasty bit of corruption you've got in your file; it looks like CDATA is malformed in several different ways. This catches all of the errors you've described:

`<tag>.*?\K((?:<!|!<)CDATA\[.*?\]+>+)(?=.*<\/tag>)`

This regex checks that the string starts with `<tag>`, gets text up to the "start" of your `CDATA` tag, and then uses `\K` to throw all of that away. Then, it looks for `!` and `<` in any order, followed by `CDATA[` and any text inside. Next comes as many `]` or `>` as we can find, though always at least one of each. The final bit of the regex is a lookahead to make sure the closing tag is present. [Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/bVbiKF/1)

Note that this will **only match one malformed tag per line.** In order to get them *all*, it's likely you'll need to run a replacement with this regex a few times. Once the regex has no more matches, you can be sure you're free of malformed tags... or at least, tags with the mutations you've described in your question.

---

As an aside, if you want to keep all "properly formatted" CDATA tags, the regex gets WAY uglier:

`<tag>.*?\K(?!<!CDATA\[[^\n\]]*\]>(?:[^>]|$))((?:<!|!<)CDATA\[.*?\]+>+)(?=.*<\/tag>)`

This includes a lookahead to assert you're not matching a "properly formatted" CDATA tag (here described as `<!CDATA[...]>`). This one runs really slow if the start `<tag>` does not have a closing `<tag>` that matches, so if that's an issue in your file(s), be warned. [Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/bVbiKF/4/)

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the help! I've testesd it and it works. It took me like 10 minutes to properly understand what it does though, that's a though regex :D
I was hoping to solve that with a single regex that i shouldn't loop, but there's no free lunch i guess ;)